Memory overflow when running graphic code in C++
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#define E exp(1)
#define Pi M_PI
using namespace std;

struct tNode{
    string data;
    tNode *pLeft, *pRight;
};

tNode *root;

tNode *newNode(string data){
    tNode *node = (tNode*)malloc(sizeof(tNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->pLeft = NULL;
    node->pRight = NULL;
    return node;
}

// Check  

int heightOfTree(tNode *root){
    if(root==NULL) return 0;
    int height = 1;
    if(root->pLeft==NULL and root->pRight==NULL) return 1;
    return 1 + max(heightOfTree(root->pLeft), heightOfTree(root->pRight));
}


//Read trê follow the order Left node - Middle Node - Right Node
void LNR(tNode *root){
    if(root!=NULL){
        if(root->pLeft != NULL) LNR(root->pLeft);
        if(root!=NULL){
            cout << root->data << " ";
        }
        if(root->pRight != NULL) LNR(root->pRight);
    }
}

void convert_to_char(char* c, string s){
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        c += s[i];
    }
    c[s.size()] = '\0';
}

int size(char *c){
    int i = 0;
    while(c[i] != NULL){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int isdigit(char c){
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int isoperator(string c){
    if(c == "+" || c == "-" || c == "*" || c == "/" || c == "^" || c == "%" || c == "^") return 1;
    return 0;
}

int isspecial(string s){
    if(s == "ln" || s == "log"  || s == "abs" || s == "cos" || s == "sin" || s == "tan" || s == "cot" || s == "acos" || s == "asin" || s == "atan" || s == "acot" || s == "cosh" || s == "sinh" || s == "tanh" || s == "coth" || s == "sqrt" || s == "cbrt")
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int pri(string c){
    if(c == "+" || c == "-") return 1;
    if(c == "%") return 2;
    if(c == "*" || c == "/") return 3;
    if(c == "^") return 4;
    if(c == "ln" || c == "log"  || c == "abs" || c == "cos" || c == "sin" || c == "tan" || c == "cot" || c == "acos" || c == "asin" || c == "atan" || c == "acot" || c == "cosh" || c == "sinh" || c == "tanh" || c == "coth" || c == "sqrt" || c == "cbrt") return 5;
    return 0;
}

int pric(char c){
    if(c == '+' || c == '-') return 1;
    if(c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%') return 2;
    if(c == '^') return 3;
    return 0;
}

int isoperatorc(char c){
    if(c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^' || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '%') return 1;
    return 0;
}

double s_to_double(string x){               //string -> double
    if(x == "e") return E;
    if(x == "pi") return Pi;
    
    double tmp = 0;
    string::iterator it = x.begin();
    
    while(*it != '.' && it != x.end()){
        tmp = tmp * 10 + (*it - 48);
        it++;
    }
    if(it == x.end()) return tmp;
    
    double a = 0;
    it = x.end() - 1;
    while(*it != '.'){
        a = (a + (*it - 48.0)) /  10;
        it--;
    }
    tmp += a;
    
    return tmp;
}

void put(char* s, queue<string> &q, stack<string> &st){         // convert expression from string to queue
    for(int i = 0; i < size(s);i++){                        // Suffix expression stored in q, operator store in st
        if(s[i] == ' ') continue;
        else if(isdigit(s[i])){                             // Read number
            string tmp;
            tmp += s[i];
            while(isdigit(s[i + 1])){
                i++;
                tmp += s[i];
            }
            if(s[i + 1] == '.'){
                tmp += s[++i];
                while(isdigit(s[i + 1])){
                    i++;
                    tmp += s[i];
                }
            }
            q.push(tmp);
        }
        else if(s[i] == '('){                               // Read open bracket
            string tmp;
            tmp += s[i];
            st.push(tmp);
        }
        else if(s[i] == ')'){                               // Read close bracket
            while(!st.empty() && st.top() != "("){
                q.push(st.top());
                st.pop();
            }
            if(!st.empty()) st.pop();
        }
        // Read special function
        else if(s[i] == 'l' && s[i + 1] == 'n'){
            i++;
            string s = "ln";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'l' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 'g'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "log";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'b' && s[i + 2] == 's'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "abs";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 's'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "cos";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 's' && s[i + 1] == 'i' && s[i + 2] == 'n'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "sin";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 't' && s[i + 1] == 'a' && s[i + 2] == 'n'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "tan";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 't'){
            i += 2;
            string s = "cot";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 's' && s[i + 2] == 'i' && s[i+3] == 'n'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "asin";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'c' && s[i + 2] == 'o' && s[i+3] == 's'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "acos";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 't' && s[i + 2] == 'a' && s[i+3] == 'n'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "atan";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'c' && s[i + 2] == 'o' && s[i+3] == 't'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "acot";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 's' && s[i + 1] == 'i' && s[i + 2] == 'n' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "sinh";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 's' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "cosh";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 't' && s[i + 1] == 'a' && s[i + 2] == 'n' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "tanh";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 't' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "coth";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 's' && s[i + 1] == 'q' && s[i + 2] == 'r' && s[i+3] == 't'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "sqrt";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'b' && s[i + 2] == 'r' && s[i+3] == 't'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "cbrt";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'p' && s[i + 1] == 'i'){
            i++;
            string s = "pi";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(isoperatorc(s[i])){
            start:
            if(st.empty() || st.top() == "("){
                string tmp;
                
                tmp += s[i];
                st.push(tmp);
                continue;
            }
            else if(pric(s[i]) > pri(st.top())){
                string tmp;
                tmp += s[i];
                st.push(tmp);
            }
            else{
                q.push(st.top());
                st.pop();
                goto start;
            }
        }
        else{
            string tmp;
            tmp += s[i];
            q.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    while(!st.empty()){
        q.push(st.top());
        st.pop();
    }
    
    queue<string> Q = q;
    while(!Q.empty()){
        cout << Q.front() << " ";
        Q.pop();
    }
}

tNode* makeExpression(queue<string> q){
    stack<tNode*> stackNode;
    while(!q.empty()){
        if(isoperator(q.front())){
            tNode* P = newNode(q.front());
            
            P->pRight = stackNode.top();
            stackNode.pop();
            
            P->pLeft = stackNode.top();
            stackNode.pop();
            
            stackNode.push(P);
            q.pop();
        }
        else if(isspecial(q.front())){
            tNode* P = newNode(q.front());
            
            P->pRight = stackNode.top();
            stackNode.pop();
            P->pLeft = NULL;
            
            stackNode.push(P);
            q.pop();
        }
        else{
            
            tNode* P = newNode(q.front());
            
            stackNode.push(P);
            q.pop();
        }
    }
    return stackNode.top();
}


// Function to draw a binary tree recursively
int xOffpos = 50;
int lCnt = 0;
int rCnt = 0;


int childCount(struct tNode* root){
    int x,y;
    if(root->pLeft == NULL && root->pRight == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }else{
        if(root->pLeft != NULL){
            x = 1+ childCount(root->pLeft);
        }
        if(root->pRight != NULL){
            y = 1+ childCount(root->pRight);

        }


        if(x>=y){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return y;
        }
    }
}




/*Code  fixed*/
//check neu la ve node sau thang xuong thi check = 0, con binh thuong check = 1
//check iff following node is drawn straight down, check = 0, else check = 1

void drawTree(struct tNode* root, int x, int y, int xOffset, int level, int check) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        // Draw left subtree
        
        int xOffset_1 = xOffset*check;
        
        if(root -> pRight != NULL && root -> pLeft == NULL){
            // Draw when node has only 1 child node
            line(x,y,x,y+100);

            drawTree(root->pRight, x, y+100, xOffset, level+1, 0); // if xOffset = 0 the following childNode will be place above each other
            
            
        }else{
        
        
        if (root->pLeft != NULL) {
            int cntLeft = childCount(root->pLeft);
            
            if (level == 0 ){
                line(x, y, x - xOffset, y + 100);
                drawTree(root->pLeft, x - xOffset, y + 100, xOffset/3, level + 1, 1 );

            }
            else
            {

                
                line(x, y, x - xOffset, y + 100);
                drawTree(root->pLeft, x - xOffset, y + 100, xOffset/3, level + 1, 1);

                
            }
        }
            

        
        
        // Draw right subtree
        if (root->pRight != NULL) {
            int cntRight = childCount(root->pRight);
            
             if (level == 0 ){
                line(x, y, x + xOffset, y + 100);
                drawTree(root->pRight, x + xOffset, y + 100, xOffset / 3, level + 1, 1);
                
                

            } else{
                
                if(cntRight < 2){
                    line(x, y, x + xOffset*(cntRight), y + 100);
                drawTree(root->pRight, x + xOffset*(cntRight), y + 100 , xOffset , level + 1, 1 );
                }else{
                    line(x, y, x + xOffset*(cntRight-1), y + 100);
                drawTree(root->pRight, x + xOffset*(cntRight-1), y + 100 , xOffset , level + 1 ,1);
                    
                }
                

            }

        }
        
    }
    
    
        
        // Draw current node
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLUE);
        fillellipse(x, y, 35, 35);
        moveto(x - 10 - 6*(root->data.size() - 1), y - 10);
        char buffer[2]; buffer[1] = '\0';
        for(int i = 0; i < root->data.size(); i++) {
            buffer[0] = root->data[i];
            outtext(buffer);
        }
    }
}



int main(){
    queue<string> q;
    stack<string> st;
    char c[1000];
    char expression[100];
    
    int option = -1;
    
    cout << "Enter Expression : ";
    
    
//  FILE *fptr;
//  
//  
//  
//  
////    fptr = fopen("Input_expression_01.txt", "r");
////    fptr = fopen("Input_expression_02.txt", "r");
////    fptr = fopen("Input_expression_03.txt", "r");
//
//    
//
//    fgets(expression, 100, fptr);
//cout << expression << endl;
//    put (expression, q, st);
    
    gets(c); cout << c << endl;
    
    put(c, q, st);

    
    
    
    root = makeExpression(q);
    
    cout << "\nLNR: \n";
    LNR(root);
    
//  Open graphic mode
    
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initwindow(1000,1000);

    setlinestyle(CENTER_LINE, 0,3); // change line thickness
    settextstyle(4, HORIZ_DIR, 1); //change character size and font
    setbkcolor(BLUE);
    
//  Create a binary tree
    
 
    
    drawTree(root, 600, 50, 200, 0, 1);

  // Close graphics mode
    getch();
    closegraph();
    
    return 0;
}

//cos(3)*7-9/(7-3) BUG!!!

I create the function to read expression and convert it to suffix one, then print it out as a binary tree using graphic in C++
When you type short expression such as : cos(1-23); 34-7/8;... the code run smoothly. But when you type longer one (maybe when expression has more than 4 operators) like: cos(3)*7-9/(7-3). It will return error code when running

You cannot malloc a non-trivial object like std::string and expect it to work. malloc doesn't create objects.

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Your code is quite long. Posting a [mre] will help us help you.

Are you using turbo c++ by any chance? I would recommend using a more modern compiler like gcc, clang or msvc etc. And some other modern graphics library.

tNode *node = (tNode*)malloc(sizeof(tNode)); -- Why are you using malloc in a C++ program?  If you had used C++ idioms and best practices, the error you are getting would probably never had occurred.   As already mentioned, malloc does not construct objects, and std::string requires construction.   Then you have this: gets(c); -- the gets() function has been removed from the standard due to it being dangerous to use.
